# The element <#text> beneath element <Target> is unrecognized in Azure

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, azure

Have a big problem here. I can't open any type of project in Visual Studio. Even when I creating a new one I get the error:

> the element <#text> beneath element  is unrecognized. C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Windows Azure Tools\1.6\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets.

If any one know please help me.

Comment: try reinstalling the Windows Azure Authoring Tools & SDK using WebPI. First try to fully uninstall Azure SDK and authoring tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sure is a installation error and i would suggest don't try to fix because there may be more such errors. I have seen a few of such errors during my work with partners and mostly these errors are caused by botched installation due to real-time, virus scanner or some unknown issues in the machine.

Here is what I could suggest:

1. Uninstall Azure SDK completely, (check program list for any Azure related entry and uninstall)
2. Restart your machine to clean from any residual setting or script running
3. Download the SDK (if Web Deploy gave you error, try downloading full SDK [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28045))
4. Disable Virus scanner for a while or any real time file system or script monitoring tool (disconnect the machine from internet if you have concern)
5. Install the SDK components.

It worked in past so I hope it will work with you as well.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar problem with the Visual Studio SDK. I had killed an experimental instance running in the debugger, and I'm wondering if it thrashed the SDK directory somehow. In my case, none of the VSIX projects would load, and it said `...\XMLTestAdapterVSIX.csproj : error  : The element <#text> beneath element <Project> is unrecognized.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\VSSDK\Microsoft.VsSDK.targets`

The IDE can't load any VSIX projects. I did a repair install of the Visual Studio SDK, but that doesn't seem to have helped.

Comment: We're having the same problem with the .net 4 targets file.  Same error message.  Tried re-installing visual studio - still not working.  Can't open a project and can't create a new one

Comment: In my case I just took all the ItemGroups and remove them all and then add part by part until it worked again

Answer (score 17):

I faced this problem too.
The error text was:

```
The element <#text> beneath element <Target> is unrecognized.
c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets
```

The solution for me was to check the indicated file against a working one from one of my coleagues. Even an XML parser or even a browser would pop-up an error when faced to this sort of error. A element under `<Target>` was corrupt. 
Instead of `<Csc ... />` I had exactly `07sc ... />`.
I fixed formatting and It worked.
Mind you that the file indicated in the error text (`Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets`) was the guilty one.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I was able to go get a file from a different machine and do a compare in winmerge.  I use Dragon Naturally Speaking and somehow I must have got something picked up recognition that got typed into that file.

Comment: I had a `<!-- -->>` way down into my target, upvote as this made me thing just enough!

Comment: I copied a snippet off StackOverflow `<PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>` (Posting for keywords)

Comment: in my case I had a dangling ß character outside of an xml node, probably a copy-paste error from a web page.

Comment: I got this error after making an errant keystroke and adding a single character outside of an xml node at the root level.   so it was 'text' under the project node.  this answer made me think to do a diff and easily fixed it.

Answer (score 15):

This also happens with generic XML errors. In my case it was `>>` somewhere in the project file. Was a copy-paste error during conflict resolution that introduced it. Sadly, the output does not include the line that has the error, so try searching for `<<` and `>>` in the file, to see if that is an issue somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

This also happens if a Property, that should be under a `<PropertyGroup>` node is a child of a `<Target>` node

wrong (produces the error):

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="CalculateVariables" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="CalculateVariables">
    <IsWrong>true</IsWrong>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

right (works):

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="CalculateVariables" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="CalculateVariables">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <IsWrong>true</IsWrong>
    <PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: I don't see the difference between the first and second example

Comment: Sorry. Fixed the sample

Comment: Solved the problem for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

There will be a Typo in the .csProject. You can copy and paste the csProj XML into
https://freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html and it will show what line is causing the problem!

Comment: Unless it auto-fixes it.. :) `>>` xml tags (double tap by mistake) is just removed

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it was caused by an automatic git merge that went wrong; there were a number of

> <<<<<<<

and

> '>>>>>>>

on some lines in the project (.csproj) file. And that was making the build fail.

Solution: remove the lines that contain those characters and reload the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and as there are over a 100  elements in the file I couldn't find the issue. I did a VS repair with the installer which took about an hour and all is working. Afterwards I did make a backup of the file.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem due to git merge conflicts inserting invisible characters into the xml file. To fix this:

1. open sln file in a text editor and copy the contents into an online xml validator (https://www.xmlvalidation.com/)
2. find location of invisible characters and either delete them or retype the line

Comment: Does not find `>>` tags that was the problem in my case.