# Visual Studio 2013 error creating Web API project: The element <#text> beneath element <Project> is unrecognized

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api2

I have a problem with my Visual Studio installation.

To reproduce it I have created a new blank solution and then:

- Add new project..
- ASP.NET Web Application
- Web API
- Create Project

Visual Studio fails to create it an I get this message:

> The element <#text> beneath element <Project> is unrecognized.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Can you please provide code or additional information?

Comment: Can you post the contents of the .sln file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The element <#text> beneath element <Target> is unrecognized in Azure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816261/the-element-text-beneath-element-target-is-unrecognized-in-azure)

Answer (score 9):

You will get such an error if csproj contains invalid XML.
I encountered this error when I accidentally removed `<!--` inside csproj file and leave `-->`:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
</Target>
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
</Target>
```

Answer (score 7):

This doesn't address the OP's precise problem, but I stumbled across this question when I had a legitimate XML break. Sometimes, these are just really hard to spot errors, even with good IDEs.

I had to go through a diff of a ~~800 line XML file until I spotted a closing bracket with an extra `>`.

I wasn't able to spot it in VS2015, VS Code, Notepad++, and even [WC3](http://validator.w3.org/)'s automated checks -- it wasn't until I did a diff between the before and after when I noticed it. Sometimes the [linters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_%28software%29) just don't catch stuff, or the suspiciously flagged area is so tiny, you miss it.
[image]

Comment: Had the same problem. All XML checkers said it was valid XML, so that didn't help.
I had some text after a closed bracket.
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>86

Not sure how you could check this automatically, but I found it by looking over the file manually.

If possible, comparing with previous version as others suggested will be the easiest. In my case, this is in the middle of a port to .Net Core, so the file was completely different with previous commit...

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem before and this is how I fixed it:

In the .csproj file I found these:

```
">>>>>>> HEAD" 
"======="
```

and this:

```
">>>>>>> fef5434acad74bc99dccc873b9feded6484317d1"
```

within the file in random locations in between the  tags. There were errors attached to all of them.

Once I removed them my project was able to load again.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That looks like something that a `git merge` or something along those lines injected into your source files, and they weren't resolved before being saved/overwritten. This has happened to me in the past as well, in general.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone gets this problem, it's due to an XML syntax error in the file.

For me it was when merging and all I did to fix was search "<<<" , ">>>" and "===" and I found the lines that were giving me a problem