# Visual Studio project wont compile on Dev machine. error : The element <#text> beneath element <Target> is unrecognized

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I have a c# project that I developed in VS2015 on my local machine. Locally it compiles and runs perfectly.
I tried transferring the project files to out Dev machine and no matter what I do I cannot get the project to load into VS

The output window reports the following:

> C:\Work\Instant Rebates\instantrebates\MTServer\MTServer.csproj :
>   error  : The element <#text> beneath element  is unrecognized.
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
>
> C:\Work\Instant Rebates\instantrebates\MTClient\MTClient.csproj :
>   error  : The element <#text> beneath element  is unrecognized.
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
>
> C:\Work\Instant Rebates\instantrebates\Website\Website.csproj : error 
>   : The element <#text> beneath element  is unrecognized. 
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
>
> C:\Work\Instant Rebates\instantrebates\DAL\DAL.csproj : error  : The
>   element <#text> beneath element  is unrecognized.  C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

Ive uninstalled all versions of Visual Studio and rebooted teh machine, and then installed VS 2015 again from scratch but to no avail.

The output of MTServe.csproj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">   <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />   <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{6EAD99C8-3A1E-4877-AD77-A0A4D2974736}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>InstantRebates.MTServer</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>InstantRebates.MTServer</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <ApplicationRevision>1</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <PublishWizardCompleted>true</PublishWizardCompleted>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>   </PropertyGroup>   <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>   </PropertyGroup>   <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>   </PropertyGroup>   <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet> </PropertyGroup>   <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet> </PropertyGroup>   <PropertyGroup>
    <StartupObject />   </PropertyGroup>   <PropertyGroup>
    <ManifestCertificateThumbprint>AD42A355D783B2951A9C77C7E7B52205C42ED25A</ManifestCertificateThumbprint> </PropertyGroup>   <PropertyGroup>
    <ManifestKeyFile>MTServer_TemporaryKey.pfx</ManifestKeyFile>   </PropertyGroup>   <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateManifests>true</GenerateManifests>   </PropertyGroup>   <PropertyGroup>
    <SignManifests>false</SignManifests>   </PropertyGroup>   <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\NLog.4.2.3\lib\net45\NLog.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="nunit.framework, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2638cd05610744eb, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\NUnit.3.2.0\lib\net45\nunit.framework.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="P23.MetaTrader4.Manager.ClrWrapper">
      <HintPath>..\DLLs\P23.MetaTrader4.Manager.ClrWrapper.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="P23.MetaTrader4.Manager.Contracts">
      <HintPath>..\DLLs\P23.MetaTrader4.Manager.Contracts.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />   </ItemGroup>   <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="MT4ServerApiWorker.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Tests\BaseTest.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Tests\MT4ServerApiWorkerTests.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Tests\MTWrapperTest.cs" />   </ItemGroup>   <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
    <None Include="NLog.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="packages.config" />   </ItemGroup>   <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="App.config.template" />   </ItemGroup>   <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DAL\DAL.csproj">
      <Project>{b147dc39-6ccf-4bb7-860f-1a6e65175579}</Project>
      <Name>DAL</Name>
    </ProjectReference>   </ItemGroup>   <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 %28x86 and x64%29</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>   </ItemGroup>   <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />   <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.   <Target Name="BeforeBuild">   </Target>   <Target Name="AfterBuild">   </Target>   --> </Project>
```

Comment: The content of MTServer.csproj could be useful. This behavior occurs only with this specific project?

Comment: I just tried opening up a second project and got a similar error

Comment: This ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816261/the-element-text-beneath-element-target-is-unrecognized-in-azure ) question seems really similar to your situation and since you have problems with any project it seems to be installation issue.

Comment: Definitely an installation issue, thats why I did the uninstalls and the clean install of 2015. Tried all suggestions on that post before I asked the question, to no avail.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30345612/4115397) worked for me when I had this problem.